# WPF - Access static class in different Namespace

Tags: wpf, static, namespaces

I have the config for my application in a static class:

```
namespace Program.Config
{
  static Class AppConfig
  {
    ...
  } 
}
```

Now, in my `xaml` I would like to access this config.

So, I added

```
xmlns:config="clr-namespace:Program.Config"
```

to my view which resides in `Program.Views`

However, accessing the `AppConfig` like

```
config:AppConfig.ConnectionConfig.conParam.ethPort
```

does not work.

What is the correct way to access members of a static class from a different namespace in WPF?

EDIT:

Ok, here comes an MWE:

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using Program.ViewModels;

namespace Program
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            MainVM vm = new MainVM();
            DataContext = vm;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

`MainVM.cs

```
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System;

namespace Program.ViewModels
{
    internal class MainVM : BindableBase
    {
        public MainVM()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

`MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Program.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:config="clr-namespace:Program.Config"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1000">


    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <Label Content="Port is:" />
        <Label Content="{Binding config:AppConfig.ConnectionConfig.conParam.ethPort}" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

`Config.cs`:

```
namespace Program
{
    using Program.Config;

    public struct ConnectionParameters
    {
        public int ethPort { get; set; }
        public string ethIp { get; set; }
    }

    public static class AppConfig
    {
        public static ConnectionConfObj ConnectionConfig { get; set; }

        static AppConfig()
        {
            ConnectionConfig = new ConnectionConfObj();
        }
    }
}

namespace Program.Config
{
    public abstract class ConfigBase
    {
        public string filepath { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConnectionConfObj : ConfigBase
    {
        public ConnectionParameters conParam { get; set; }

        public ConnectionConfObj()
        {
            ConnectionParameters _conParam = new ConnectionParameters();
            _conParam.ethPort = 8;

            conParam = _conParam;
        }
    }

}
```

In the scope of the program, the structure of the config makes sense like this, since I read multiple configs from different sources and want to present them in one AppConfig for the program.

Comment: is it relevant that Program is spelled in two different ways here?

Comment: Ah, no sorry, just a typo. The Program has a different name in reality and I just redacted it here.

Comment: Then how about a reproducible example? How are NetworkConfig and NetworkConfig.IP defined? Are you using `x:Static` in the XAML? If AppConfig is a class, `x:Static` can reference a member of that class and that's it. Not a member of a member. If AppConfig is a namespace contained in Program.Config, and NetworkConfig is a class in that namespace and IP is a static member of that NetworkConfig class, that'll work. But I'm guessing it's a member of a member.

Comment: `{Binding ID, Source={x:Static config:AppConfig.NetworkConfig}}` might be the answer, but you've provided so little information that it's impossible to say anything definite.

Comment: Thanks for what I hope will be the first of many, many updates until I have the information I need (actually, just one more update, with everything I've requested, would be ideal). `{config:AppConfig.NetworkConfig.IP}` is a nonsense in XAML. If you want to do something with a static class member, you want `{x:Static nmspc:ClassName.MemberName}`. Of course, I have no idea of the context here. You need to show *where and how* you are using this in the XAML. Please provide a complete reproducible example.

Comment: `AppConfig` class is `internal` by default, you'll need to make it `public`

Comment: Added MWE, sorry I didn't include it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a static class member (including enum values) in your XAML, use the [x:Static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-static-markup-extension) [markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml) as follows: `{x:Static nmspc:ClassName.MemberName}` (or `{x:Static nmspc:EnumTypeName.EnumValueName}` -- enum values are really static members of a static class). You get a namespace prefix, one class name optionally preceded by intermediate namespaces, and one member name, and that's all it does. If you need a property of `MemberName`, make the static reference the Source of a Binding. A Binding can have a path to a property of a property:

```
<Label 
    Content="{Binding conParam.ethPort, Source={x:Static config:AppConfig.ConnectionConfig)}" 
    />
```

---